# Questions about boolean class properties naming convention for is/has

Tags: java, naming

I have these properties for a patient represented by class Patient. I am wondering what is best practice to name them?

1. whether she is in lactation period: boolean
2. whether she is pregnant: boolean
3. whether she is preparing for pregnant: boolean
4. whether he/she suffers low blood glucose recently: boolean
5. whether he/she has complications: boolean

a first thought was to name them as:

```
boolean isInLactationPeriod;
boolean isPregnant;
boolean isPreparingPregnant;
boolean hasSufferedLowBloodGlucoseRecently;
boolean hasComplications;
```

However I also come across suggestions that java properties should not be name with leading is / has, but to leave them to the getter / setter method, e.g.

```
boolean pregnant;
boolean isPregnant() {
    return pregnant;
}
```

Which one is better?

Comment: It does not really matter as long as the naming is consistent and correct.

Comment: I think `pregnant` as a boolean state variable is perfectly clear. The `is` prefix is a bit redundant imo. Sometimes the `is`/`has` prefix is left out from boolean get-methods, but I think that's bad practice.

Comment: "This question is opinion-based. It is not currently accepting answers." This question seems to be closed for the wrong reason. Yes, this question is opinion-based somehow but not only. Naming conventions for variables and getters/setters/issers.. etc strongly relate to code design which if not handled correctly can lead to accumulated technical debts and code readibility in the future.

Answer (score 5):

It might be more of a convenience based or opinion based. But you can use the `isPregnant` as it is more or less making it clear.

See the Java docs:

> 8.3.2 Boolean properties
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match
>   the pattern:
>
> public boolean is();
>
> This “is” method may be provided instead of a
>   “get” method, or it may be provided in addition to a
>   “get” method. In either case, if the “is”
>   method is present for a boolean property then we will use the
>   “is” method to read the property value. An example
>   boolean property might be:
>
> ```
> public boolean isMarsupial(); 
> public void setMarsupial(boolean m);
> ```

Answer (score 4):

**Both options looks good , but i will prefer the latter one.**

> is prefix can be used for boolean variables and methods. isSet,
>   isVisible, isFinished, isFound, isOpen This is the naming convention
>   for boolean methods and variables used by Sun for the Java core
>   packages.
>
> Using the is prefix solves a common problem of choosing bad boolean
>   names like status or flag. isStatus or isFlag simply doesn't fit, and
>   the programmer is forced to chose more meaningful names.
>
> Setter methods for boolean variables must have set prefix as in:
>
> void setFound(boolean isFound);
>
> There are a few alternatives to the is prefix that fits better in some
>   situations. These are has, can and should prefixes:
>
> boolean hasLicense();   boolean canEvaluate();   boolean shouldAbort
>   = false;

Please refer [this](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Specific)

> Also, naming field as `pregnant` looks more suitable and getters /
>   setters names will make more sense. `Is` is a verb , which can be
>   avoided being used in variable names.

Comment: So both pregnant and isPregnant are good names?

Comment: @user3033644 yes both looks fine, but `pregnant` looks better, with getters/setters as mentioned.

Comment: I think I would go with `boolean pregnant` and not `boolean isPregnant` for the same reason that I would go with `int age` instead of `int hasAge` or `int isOfAge`.

Comment: @aioobe yes, even i would prefer latter

Comment: You seem to advocate using the `is` prefix by reading the first line in your answer.

Comment: @aioobe yup rectified :)

Answer (score 1):

#### The convention

Basically, the SCJP 6 book said the following about the bean naming conventions:

- your variable should not have a *is*;
- getters should begin with *get*;
- for booleans, *get* can be replaced with *is*.

This matches [Rahul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797043/1734119).

There was nothing about *has*, so ideally, I guess you should use *is* if your variable name is an adjective and *get* otherwise.

#### The limits of conventions

Then, those are conventions and people like me will appreciate you respect them (and also some tools and frameworks such as Spring), but in some cases *has* can make more sense to the human reader. If you want to break the convention, it's up to you and your best judgement.